# How to select the only date/string on a table

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a query that returns a table that only contains 1 value (Date) per column and the rest of the rows are NULLS, I would like to select from each column the only value and ignore the NULLS.

For example, let's say my table look something like this:

```
       Col1      Col2      Col3
     1/1/2018    Null      Null
     Null      1/2/2019    Null
     Null        Null    23/3/2019
```

And in return, I want something like

```
       Col1      Col2      Col3
     1/1/2018   1/2/2019  23/3/2019
```

If instead of a date it was a number, it would be easy just to sum the column, but since it's a date, I don't know how to ignore nulls.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which database you are using? And is this true that there will be only one  value in one column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this very limited example, you could use `MAX()`

```
SELECT MAX(col1), MAX(col2), MAX(col3)
FROM your_Table
```